# Change picture after 3sec in Tkinter Canvas

Tags: image, python-3.x, tkinter

In a Tkinter canvas, I want to display pic1.gif and after 3 seconds change the picture to pic2.gif. When I run the program below, it shows pic2.gif straight away.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep


canvas_width = 300
canvas_height =300

master = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width, 
           height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

img = PhotoImage(file="pic1.gif")
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
sleep(3)
canvas.delete("all")
img = PhotoImage(file="pic2.gif")
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)
mainloop()
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `time.sleep` in tkinter, you have to use the mainloop, which you access with the `after` method.

```
from tkinter import *

canvas_width = 300
canvas_height =300

master = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width, 
           height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

img = PhotoImage(file="pic1.gif")
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)

def change_img():
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.img = PhotoImage(file="pic2.gif")
    canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=canvas.img)

master.after(3000, change_img) # run the change_img function in 3,000 milliseconds

mainloop()
```

Comment: John Shipman's / New Mexico Tech's third-party documentation for tkinter is one of the best references for Tkinter.  The `after()` function is described at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html

Comment: To change the image after every 3 seconds, I had to call  `master.after(3000, change_img)` in `change_img()` at end, 
I hope `master.after` is some sort of listener and this would not go in infinite recursion. Is there any better alternative for this?